# What is the best way to parse Paypal NVP in PHP?

Tags: php, paypal-nvp

I need a function that will correctly parse NVP into PHP array. I have been using code provided by paypal but it did not work for when string length was specified next to the name.

Here is what i have so far.

```
private function parseNVP($nvpstr)
{
    $intial=0;
    $nvpArray = array();

    while(strlen($nvpstr))
    {
        //postion of Key
        $keypos= strpos($nvpstr,'=');
        //position of value
        $valuepos = strpos($nvpstr,'&') ? strpos($nvpstr,'&'): strlen($nvpstr);

        /*getting the Key and Value values and storing in a Associative Array*/
        $keyval=substr($nvpstr,$intial,$keypos);
        $vallength=$valuepos-$keypos-1;
        // check if the length is explicitly specified
        if($braketpos = strpos($keyval,'['))
        {
            // override value length
            $vallength = substr($keyval,$braketpos+1,strlen($keyval)-$braketpos-2);
            // get rid of brackets from key name
            $keyval = substr($keyval,0,$braketpos);
        }
        $valval=substr($nvpstr,$keypos+1,$vallength);
        //decoding the respose
        if (isValidXMLString("<".urldecode($keyval).">".urldecode( $valval)."</".urldecode($keyval).">"))
            $nvpArray[urldecode($keyval)] =urldecode( $valval);
        $nvpstr=substr($nvpstr,$keypos+$vallength+2,strlen($nvpstr));
     }
    return $nvpArray;
}
```

This function works most of the time.

Answer (score 16):

The best way is the [parse_str](http://us.php.net/parse_str) function. It will parse a URLencoded string into a PHP array.

So your code would look like:

```
private function parseNVP($nvpstr)
{
  $paypalResponse = array();
  parse_str($nvpstr,$paypalResponse);
  return $paypalResponse;
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect since parse_str on "note[6]=aaaaa stuff=2" will result in
array('note'=>array(5=>'aaaaa '),'stuff'=>2)
the result should be array('note'=>'aaaaa ', 'stuff'=>2)

Comment: No. The result should not be `array('note'=>'aaaaa ', 'stuff'=>2)`. for that you'd have "note=aaaaa&stuff=2". My answer is not incorrect. I have built a paypal payment gateway integration in PHP using the code I sent. It processes thousands of transactions a month just fine.

Comment: The string length should not be specified next to the string like that. It's not how PayPal NVP works. Read their manual. "The request and response are URL-encoded" https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_NVPAPIOverview

Comment: The result for note[6]=aaaaa &stuff=2 should be array('note'=>'aaaaa ', 'stuff'=>2). What you use works 99% of the time. And the manuals are great but they don't match code at times. I know for a fact that PayPal sometimes sends NVP with length specified, Usually it happens when customers enter notes on PayPal page.

Comment: I've been using the code supplied in production for years with no issues whatsoever...

Comment: Please note that - starting from PHP 5.3.9 - the number of variables parsed by parse_str is subject to the `max_input_vars` configuration option ( [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars) ) with a default of 1000. Parsing large TransactionSearch-results are very likely to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Googling a lot I've found this:

```
function deformatNVP($nvpstr) {

    $intial=0;
    $nvpArray = array();


    while(strlen($nvpstr)){
        //postion of Key
        $keypos= strpos($nvpstr,'=');
        //position of value
        $valuepos = strpos($nvpstr,'&') ? strpos($nvpstr,'&'): strlen($nvpstr);

        /*getting the Key and Value values and storing in a Associative Array*/
        $keyval=substr($nvpstr,$intial,$keypos);
        $valval=substr($nvpstr,$keypos+1,$valuepos-$keypos-1);
        //decoding the respose
        $nvpArray[urldecode($keyval)] =urldecode( $valval);
        $nvpstr=substr($nvpstr,$valuepos+1,strlen($nvpstr));
     }
     return $nvpArray;
}
```

[Source](https://forums.modx.com/thread/48918/paypal-pro-integration-curl-problem).

**I DO NOT own this code and I don't have tested it, so use it with care.**