# PHP and NVP (Name-Value Pair) lists?

Tags: php, paypal, nvp

Working a bit with PayPal and stumbled on the NVP response. I´m used to working with JSON and XML as a response format. But have never worked with the NVP "simplified" format. Why aren´t they and others using JSON/XML instead of NVP?

A list can look like this SomeList.Item(0).name

Is there a good way to work with NVP in PHP?

Hope somebody can explain the pros with NVP over JSON and XML and a way to work with NVP in PHP. Like how to iterate through a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use PHP's [`parse_str()`](http://us.php.net/parse_str) function.
It parses a string like

```
user=test&password=123
```

into a PHP array in this form:

```
Array
(
    [user] => test
    [password] => 123
)
```

Comment: Please note that - starting from PHP 5.3.9 - the number of variables parsed by parse_str is subject to the `max_input_vars` configuration option ( [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars) ) with a default of 1000. Parsing of large TransactionSearch results are very likely to fail.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for the function [parse_str](http://us.php.net/parse_str)

Here is another example I found.

[Parse Paypal NVP in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520135/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-paypal-nvp-in-php)